# How to validate Order ID sent by Google is Real or Fake, after in-app-purchase

Tags: android, aidl, android-inapp-purchase

Below I'm including the JSON format of two Order Id, one is Real and the other is Fake.

**This is the Real Transaction**

```
{
  "orderId" : "GPA.3380-7694-2321-27312",
  "productId" : "com.inappbilling.adfreepremium",
  "purchaseInfo" : {
    "purchaseData" : {
      "autoRenewing" : false,
      "developerPayload" : "inapp:com.inappbilling.adfreepremium:dc801c91-99e8-4b3e-a0bc-709ef38073b5:C3bWYcq7z4Wa91OdEIduBRjFUqT2",
      "orderId" : "GPA.3380-7694-2321-27312",
      "packageName" : "com.inappbilling",
      "productId" : "com.inappbilling.adfreepremium",
      "purchaseState" : "PurchasedSuccessfully",
      "purchaseTime" : {
        "date" : 11,
        "day" : 3,
        "hours" : 18,
        "minutes" : 57,
        "month" : 9,
        "seconds" : 38,
        "time" : 1507728458795,
        "timezoneOffset" : -330,
        "year" : 117
      },
      "purchaseToken" : "npnilkgoilhcnfanoehgamoi.AO-J1Ow0I02vlg7MeiW-OSinzpskLBAljS7DJw2oxqR0XcQUXJmlvFQ_DbYv0F5D_VLzlOcjWsndwG3SBEW7hEcazq072QVtWo1VGLDumdo3oiIcumJEAjl9odzI4ba9MiCcmh969cASTBSOsKm08JlLu14oL2Vljw800U7wxJM5Sj5vmPhx-R8"
    },
    "responseData" : "{\"orderId\":\"GPA.3380-7694-2321-27312\",\"packageName\":\"com.inappbilling\",\"productId\":\"com.inappbilling.adfreepremium\",\"purchaseTime\":1507728458795,\"purchaseState\":0,\"developerPayload\":\"inapp:com.inappbilling.adfreepremium:dc801c91-99e8-4b3e-a0bc-709ef38073b5:C3bWYcq7z4Wa91OdEIduBRjFUqT2\",\"purchaseToken\":\"npnilkgoilhcnfanoehgamoi.AO-J1Ow0I02vlg7MeiW-OSinzpskLBAljS7DJw2oxqR0XcQUXJmlvFQ_DbYv0F5D_VLzlOcjWsndwG3SBEW7hEcazq072QVtWo1VGLDumdo3oiIcumJEAjl9odzI4ba9MiCcmh969cASTBSOsKm08JlLu14oL2Vljw800U7wxJM5Sj5vmPhx-R8\"}",
    "signature" : "CxoItQfNc4IQL1WpRFalGdTc+iVf4cr9DMpfWptqBG++3CPcnn3u4zAQXwR6kwN45A6hG01raAxHCgv727Xy+AO0UzQ5aBYmEyvhwhuQE4fNk5cbtWubFBrCLGPeOJ28MLXAwQd71dfL4X7cyb9+udzGo+HUPcVbThILG+hdhKeP7YSIgnE0UdZdDaFaNfFaBEsLPkodXi2aVGfr+dRuPHvHE+TdEGQffkGPXPNf3ew0lGVRbLiuZDahuLIoVXrBrcuN1SrjGTHzkVv9F48u8s/HPSdpBRwYww4jc+HB/VQX1wmHgIHQ4RjD500nx+oeh6Nm7FMeKHE9XuEK8bYU+Q=="
  },
  "purchaseTime" : {
    "date" : 11,
    "day" : 3,
    "hours" : 18,
    "minutes" : 57,
    "month" : 9,
    "seconds" : 38,
    "time" : 1507728458795,
    "timezoneOffset" : -330,
    "year" : 117
  },
  "purchaseToken" : "npnilkgoilhcnfanoehgamoi.AO-J1Ow0I02vlg7MeiW-OSinzpskLBAljS7DJw2oxqR0XcQUXJmlvFQ_DbYv0F5D_VLzlOcjWsndwG3SBEW7hEcazq072QVtWo1VGLDumdo3oiIcumJEAjl9odzI4ba9MiCcmh969cASTBSOsKm08JlLu14oL2Vljw800U7wxJM5Sj5vmPhx-R8"
}
```

**Below is the Fake Transaction**

```
{
  "orderId" : "2809638644339204951.3288963171986848",
  "productId" : "com.inappbilling.adfreepremium",
  "purchaseInfo" : {
    "purchaseData" : {
      "autoRenewing" : false,
      "developerPayload" : "inapp:com.inappbilling.adfreepremium:516c4d76-4d6e-4555-a112-df2c3fc38f19:13a07zRwuBh4NOSTbtrnNhzQqfo1",
      "orderId" : "2809638644339204951.3288963171986848",
      "packageName" : "com.inappbilling",
      "productId" : "com.inappbilling.adfreepremium",
      "purchaseState" : "PurchasedSuccessfully",
      "purchaseTime" : {
        "date" : 27,
        "day" : 6,
        "hours" : 21,
        "minutes" : 56,
        "month" : 0,
        "seconds" : 15,
        "time" : 1517086575443,
        "timezoneOffset" : -60,
        "year" : 118
      },
      "purchaseToken" : "hszxbxhxuxwjirzrpzgdaiiy"
    },
    "responseData" : "{\"orderId\":\"2809638644339204951.3288963171986848\",\"packageName\":\"com.inappbilling\",\"productId\":\"com.inappbilling.adfreepremium\",\"purchaseTime\":1517086575443,\"purchaseState\":0,\"developerPayload\":\"inapp:com.inappbilling.adfreepremium:516c4d76-4d6e-4555-a112-df2c3fc38f19:13a07zRwuBh4NOSTbtrnNhzQqfo1\",\"purchaseToken\":\"hszxbxhxuxwjirzrpzgdaiiy\"}",
    "signature" : "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"
  },
  "purchaseTime" : {
    "date" : 27,
    "day" : 6,
    "hours" : 21,
    "minutes" : 56,
    "month" : 0,
    "seconds" : 15,
    "time" : 1517086575443,
    "timezoneOffset" : -60,
    "year" : 118
  },
  "purchaseToken" : "hszxbxhxuxwjirzrpzgdaiiy"
}
```

***How will I validate that the particular Order Id is Valid or Not?***

Comment: i also get this kind of order id "orderId" : "2809638644339204951.3288963171986848"  generated by some user and this kind of order id couldn't find in Google Play Console under "Order management" any solution?

Answer (score 1):

According to what I have understood from your question check my below answer, You have to store your order id either in your local database or server side database.

you can retrieve the information after user purchased the item, you can get response. you can store order id from that response in your database.

check this link for more information:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

you can verify that you can purchased correct product or not by using developer payload, check this links link1 and link2. After purchasing the product you can verify either user has purchased the same product or not.

Hope it will solve your query